# Stylelint indentation rule returns false negative on multi-line mixin

Tags: css, sass, stylelint

I have an app that uses Stylelint to enforce stylistic rules inside styles, but here, Stylelint complains about indentation when a long line is split in half by Prettier.

```css
@include box-shadow(
  var(--shadow-offset) var(--shadow-offset) 0 var(--shadow-spread)
    $color-white, // complains here about 2 extra whitespaces
  var(--shadow-offset) var(--shadow-offset) $color-red
);
```

raises this error `Expected indentation of 8 spaces (indentation)`

I tried
`/* stylelint-disable-line indentation */`
`/* stylelint-disable-line */`
only
`/* stylelint-disable */` gets rid of the "error".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Prettier alongside Stylelint, [you should extend](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/get-started) the appropriate Prettier shared config, e.g. [stylelint-config-prettier-scss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint-config-prettier-scss), in your Stylelint configuration:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "stylelint-config-standard-scss"
    "stylelint-config-prettier-scss"
  ]
}
```

This config turns off all the rules that conflict with Prettier. It should be [placed last](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint-config-prettier#user-content-installation) in the `extends` array.

Prettier is then responsible more enforcing stylistic conventions, like whitespace, and Stylelint is focused on helping you avoid errors and enforce non-stylistic conventions, e.g. what units you want to allow in your codebase.

Comment: This is my stylelint config https://gist.github.com/theolavaux/66d67078232e08f1f159bd1125260fed

Comment: I already have `"stylelint-config-prettier"` inside `extends`

Comment: It needs to be the last config in the extends array (as, in your case, the indentation rule is being turned on in the stylelint-config-standard-scss config). I've updated my answer to make this clearer. You'll also want to extend stylelint-config-prettier-scss, rather than stylelint-config-prettier.